# AfNetworking error Post

Tags: ios, json, ios5, afnetworking

I recently started using AfNetworking in my projects.
I created an AFClient, implement all the parameter and everything is in order to **GET** methods.
However, I am not able to make a **POST** method:
There is my code:

```
            NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"TexttoInsert", @"question",
                                id,@"user_id",
                                nr1,@"number1",
                                nr2, @"number2",
                                nil];


        [[MYClient sharedInstance] postPath:@"insert" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {

                                            NSLog(@"%@", JSON);

                                       }
                                       failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                           NSLog(@"RequestOperation:%@",operation);  
                                           NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);  
                                       }];
```

I get this error, and am not able to solve it.

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 400" UserInfo=0x6cb6330 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"success":false,"error":400,"message":"Bad Request"}, 

AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6a893e0>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://myMainUrl/insert, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest http://myMainUrl/insert>}
```

Comment: That looks like your server is being hit correctly, but your server is returning a 400 error code. Do you have the logs from the server to see what's going on there?

Comment: Do you have any documentation about how the post message should look. Because there is no error with the way you use `AFNetworking`, as the error states the responds with an error `Bad Request` which normally means that you are not meting the requirments for the request.

Comment: according to the server, I am sending the parameters in JSON format, the parameters are within a couple of braces,{question=..., etc} and should not be this way, for the server accepts them. Any idea to solve that in the client side?

Comment: I have a solution to create another ApiClient without be based in [AFJSONRequestOperation class], but i preferred to have everything in just one APiClient. Any idea?